# Cross platform solution for input on stdin with arrow keys support?

Tags: c, input, scanf, fgets, arrow-keys

I know there are many similar questions, but I could not find answers clear enough.

I am writing something that resembles a little primitive shell in C. I am constantly querying the user to enter commands, which I process. To read a line, I use `fgets()`. It works really nice (I have to remove the `\n` every time though), but if I want to move the cursor when typing something, the raw key codes get put into the console instead. Not only can I not use the up and down arrow keys to get previous commands, I am also unable to correct any typos without deleting everything with backspace until the typo and then typing stuff back again.

The same happens when using `scanf()`, so `fgets()` is not the culprit. Interestingly enough, it works just fine when I'm trying on Windows. Also, as I said, for example the backspace key actually deletes characters…

I know I could use `ncurses`, but I would rather find another elegant solution…

Comment: The C standard is based on stream-oriented input and output. There is no cross-platform solution which does not involve third-party libraries.

Comment: Assuming that you're willing to use third-party libraries, though... https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: `ncurses` is probably your best bet.

Comment: There's also Gnu Readline.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker doesn't that only work on Linux/UNIX? I'm trying to write portable code which works on Windows as well

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a library like `readline`.
Don’t get entangled in ‘portable code.’
You can use `Conditional Inclusion` to stay compatible on different platforms.